# HTML5 Form Validation with Capybara, PhantomJS and Poltergeist

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I have a modal dialog (bootstrap `modal-content`) with a form on it.

The form has a field for an email:

`<input class="form-control" data-error="Email address is invalid" required="required" id="email_to_forward" name="email_to_forward" placeholder="Enter email" type="email">`

The form also has a button:

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="forward" name="forward" value="forward">Forward</button>`

The expected behavior is as follows:

- Given I enter an invalid email address
- When I click submit
- Then the dialog should remain visible

This works as expected if I do a manual test.

This works as expected if I run the automation using the Firefox selenium driver.

This does not work if I use poltergeist with PhantomJS.
As soon as it clicks the submit button, the dialog is no longer visible.

Does PhantomJS and Poltergeist support HTML5 validation?

Comment: I just ran into this as well. It doesn't look like it includes HTML form validation.